# Live Search from multiple JSON files, Javascript, AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have to implement a search bar using AJAX and jQuery that displays results from 3 JSON files. At the moment I have it working with one but I am not sure how I might adapt this to live search 3 separate JSON files simultaneously.

```
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
search.addEventListener('keydown', liveSearch);

function liveSearch() {
    const searchField = search.value;
    const myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

    $.getJSON('weekday.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if ((val.Title.search(myExp) !== -1) || (val.Description.search(myExp) !== -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<strong>' + val.Title + '</strong>';
                output += '<p>' + val.Description + ' - ' + val.Price + '</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#output').html(output);
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use 3 getJSON's ... and `$.when`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$.when` to execute multiple async promise
```

```
$.when(
   $.getJSON('weekday1.json'),
   $.getJSON('weekday2.json'),
   $.getJSON('weekday3.json')
).then(function (results) {
   var r1 = results[0]; // result in weekday1.json
   var r2 = results[1]; // result in weekday2.json
   var r3 = results[2]; // result in weekday3.json
})
```

Note: the promise(.then function) will only be resolved after all async task are resolved.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: I have tried this however it doesn't work and I get a warning: - jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Comment: sorry, some typos in the example. pls try again and make sure you included jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

'results' in the code provided by arfai1213 does not return an array that can be used as suggested.

Splitting results as per the code below returns separate arrays that can be used.

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('./data/file1.json'),
    $.getJSON('./data/file2.json')
).then(function (r1, r2) {
    $.each(r1[0], function(key, val){
        //do something
    })
    $.each(r2[0], function(key, val){
        //do something
    })
});
```